# Using a custom UITableView containing an image view cell with UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

In my new app, I am trying to adopt AutoLayout throughout. In one of my table views, I have an image view and a label. If I do this in my controller's `viewDidLoad:` method

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

the row is not high enough to accommodate the image. (I have added fixed width and height constraints to the image view).

If I remove the statement, then the height of the cell is the height as set in IB.

Is there a method I have to implement in my `UITableCell` class to tell the AutoLayout system my minimum height requirement? Or did I do something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Don't use fixed height constraints if your cell height is depended on content. You can us minimum height constraints, or even better, use fixed space from lower edge of cell (remove height constraints). If possible, please post a screenshot of your IB and constraints. I'm bad in imagination.

Comment: check out this....may be you found something.....http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could never figure this out using IB. However, I did get success adding the constraints manually, so I thought it worth sharing my complete solution. (Remember: an image view, a label, dynamic text). I want my image to always be 80 by 80, no matter how big the content gets.

Enjoy.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ( !(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) ) return nil;

    // TODO: Add an imageview and populate it
    _titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,20)];
    _titleLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
    _titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.contentView addSubview:_titleLabel];

    _albumArtImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    [_albumArtImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self.contentView addSubview:_albumArtImageView];

    NSMutableArray* constraints = [NSMutableArray new];
    UIView* contentView = self.contentView;

    [_titleLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    // _titleLabel to contentView
    [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:_titleLabel
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                            toItem:contentView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                            // as font grow, space from top grows
                            multiplier:1.8
                            constant:30]];

    // similarly for bottom
    [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:contentView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                            toItem:_titleLabel
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLastBaseline
                            multiplier:1.3
                            constant:8]];


    [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:contentView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                            toItem:nil
                            attribute:0
                            multiplier:1.0
                            constant:80]];


    // Now the imageView
    [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:_albumArtImageView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                            toItem:nil
                            attribute:0
                            multiplier:1.0
                            constant:80]];

    [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintWithItem:_albumArtImageView
                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                            toItem:nil
                            attribute:0
                            multiplier:1.0
                            constant:80]];

    // for horizontal
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:
            [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-2-[_albumArtImageView]-5-[_titleLabel]-15-|"
            options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_titleLabel,_albumArtImageView) ]];



    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];

    return self;
}
```